# Creating a reusable JS file - Import - export not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a reusable JS to load some files form the server, but this is working differently if I have the code together or if I have on separate files and I dont understand why

All together:

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');

function addAssetsFromManifest(file) {
  const loadManifest = fetch('/path/manifest.json');
  loadManifest.then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
      const loadJson = resp.json();
      loadJson.then((json) => {
        const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptTag.src = `/${json[file]}`;
        const { body } = document;
        body.appendChild(scriptTag);
        return json;
      });
      return loadJson.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
    }
    return loadManifest.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
  });
}


 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   addAssetsFromManifest('path/js/file.js');
});
```

but if I split the code like this is not working:
addAssetsFromManifest.js:

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');

export default function addAssetsFromManifest(file) {
  const loadManifest = fetch('/path/manifest.json');
  loadManifest.then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
      const loadJson = resp.json();
      loadJson.then((json) => {
        const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptTag.src = `/${json[file]}`;
        const { body } = document;
        body.appendChild(scriptTag);
        return json;
      });
      return loadJson.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
    }
    return loadManifest.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
  });
}
```

loader.js

```
import addAssetsFromManifest from './addAssetsFromManifest';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  addAssetsFromManifest('path/js/file.js');
});
```

is not working at all. I am not sure if this is related worth webpack or not, if yes I will share `package.json` and  `webpack.config.js`

Any ideas

Comment: is this running in node?

Comment: Is running on the browser

Comment: It ended to be the webpack configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using require and modules.export

```
module.export = function addAssetsFromManifest(file){......}
```

and

```
const addAssetsFromManifest = require("./addAssetsFromManifest")
```